# Debugger with Breakpoint and Variable read/set capability

Tags: variables, ide

Is there any free/open or commercial/paid Arduino IDE Sketch Debugger (not Atmel chip factory standard tool set) with Breakpoint and Variable read/set capability?

I read about VM on web. Is there any similar product?

Comment: have you looking into using simavr and gdb?

Comment: Wonder if simavr and gdb work at Arduino sketch language or Atmel factory tools (Atmel Studio) C language?

Comment: All it does is simulate an avr chip; It is tool agnostic. You will need to be able to compile with debugging data to use gdb, and I'm not sure how to make arduino do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is something quite close to what you are asking.
You need either the (more expensive) ICEMKII (iirc) or the (cheaper) AVRDragon.
Then it's possible to [use](http://awtfy.com/category/microcontrollers/) it with gdb.

In practice the AVR supports only one breakpoint, so what happens is that the binary in flash will be dynamically patched.
This will slightly reduce the life of the AVR, but I think it's fairly acceptable. One can always use Arduino UNO with the original DIP package for AVR, mounted on a socket. Then it's sufficient to replace the burnt microcontroller and keep the rest (but it's hundreds of thousands of programming cycles before the AVR fails).

Answer (score 1):

There is an on-target [debugger](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/libraries/Debug/Debug.hh) in [Cosa](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa) and a port of the library for [Arduino/AVR](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-Debug). It allows conditional and unconditional break- and observation points, simple call back-trace, variable read, memory status check, memory dump, etc.

[image: Debug Demo Sketch]

The debugger is implemented as a small command handler that is executed on the target (Arduino). A set of macros are used to mark break-points, variables to observe, etc.

Please see the debugger [demo sketch](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-Debug/blob/master/examples/DebugDemo/DebugDemo.ino) for more details.